Animating a path of an SVG icon to spin clockwise from center with CSS
I'm trying to spin/rotate the inner path of this SVG so that it spins clockwise.
Right now the path is spinning as if it was around a bigger circle. How do I spin the icon from the center point and rotate it clockwise?


  #circle-arrows {
    animation: loader 1.25s infinite;
  }

  @keyframes loader {
    0% {
      rotate: 0deg;
    }

    100% {
      border-radius: 50%;
      rotate: 180deg;
    }
  }
<svg width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
      <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" />
      <path
        d="M23 14.864C23 17.696 20.737 20 17.956 20c-.11 0-.236 0-.346-.016V20H6.044c-.11 0-.22 0-.33-.016C3.09 19.808 1 17.584 1 14.864c0-2.16 1.304-4.016 3.159-4.784.157-2.512 2.2-4.48 4.698-4.48.487 0 .959.08 1.399.224h.015A4.993 4.993 0 0 1 14.137 4c2.782 0 5.044 2.304 5.044 5.136 0 .24-.015.48-.062.72C21.35 10.4 23 12.432 23 14.864z"
        fill="#000" fill-rule="nonzero" />
      <path id="circle-arrows"
        d="M16.348 12.98c-.499 2.072-2.209 3.52-4.372 3.52a4.492 4.492 0 0 1-3.082-1.243l-.755.757a.376.376 0 0 1-.264.111.378.378 0 0 1-.375-.375v-2.625c0-.205.17-.375.375-.375H10.5c.205 0 .375.17.375.375 0 .1-.04.193-.11.264l-.804.802a2.991 2.991 0 0 0 4.594-.62c.14-.23.21-.452.31-.687.03-.082.087-.134.176-.134h1.125c.106 0 .187.088.187.187 0 .013 0 .03-.005.042zm.152-2.105c0 .205-.17.375-.375.375H13.5a.378.378 0 0 1-.375-.375c0-.1.04-.193.11-.264l.81-.809A3.016 3.016 0 0 0 12 9c-1.043 0-2.01.539-2.555 1.43-.14.229-.21.451-.31.686-.03.082-.087.134-.176.134H7.793a.189.189 0 0 1-.187-.187v-.042C8.11 8.94 9.838 7.5 12 7.5c1.149 0 2.267.457 3.099 1.243l.762-.757a.376.376 0 0 1 .264-.111c.205 0 .375.17.375.375v2.625z"
        fill="#FFF" fill-rule="nonzero" />
    </g>
  </svg>




You may add transform-origin: center for the #circle-arrows

@enxaneta thank you for the suggestion and simplifying my question.

As @enxaneta says, add transform-origin: center to #circle-arrows. Read more about transform-origin.


#circle-arrows {
    animation: loader 1.25s infinite;
  }

  @keyframes loader {
    0% {
      rotate: 0deg;
    }

    100% {
      border-radius: 50%;
      rotate: 180deg;
    }
  }
<svg width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
      <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" />
      <path
        d="M23 14.864C23 17.696 20.737 20 17.956 20c-.11 0-.236 0-.346-.016V20H6.044c-.11 0-.22 0-.33-.016C3.09 19.808 1 17.584 1 14.864c0-2.16 1.304-4.016 3.159-4.784.157-2.512 2.2-4.48 4.698-4.48.487 0 .959.08 1.399.224h.015A4.993 4.993 0 0 1 14.137 4c2.782 0 5.044 2.304 5.044 5.136 0 .24-.015.48-.062.72C21.35 10.4 23 12.432 23 14.864z"
        fill="#000" fill-rule="nonzero" />
      <path id="circle-arrows"
        d="M16.348 12.98c-.499 2.072-2.209 3.52-4.372 3.52a4.492 4.492 0 0 1-3.082-1.243l-.755.757a.376.376 0 0 1-.264.111.378.378 0 0 1-.375-.375v-2.625c0-.205.17-.375.375-.375H10.5c.205 0 .375.17.375.375 0 .1-.04.193-.11.264l-.804.802a2.991 2.991 0 0 0 4.594-.62c.14-.23.21-.452.31-.687.03-.082.087-.134.176-.134h1.125c.106 0 .187.088.187.187 0 .013 0 .03-.005.042zm.152-2.105c0 .205-.17.375-.375.375H13.5a.378.378 0 0 1-.375-.375c0-.1.04-.193.11-.264l.81-.809A3.016 3.016 0 0 0 12 9c-1.043 0-2.01.539-2.555 1.43-.14.229-.21.451-.31.686-.03.082-.087.134-.176.134H7.793a.189.189 0 0 1-.187-.187v-.042C8.11 8.94 9.838 7.5 12 7.5c1.149 0 2.267.457 3.099 1.243l.762-.757a.376.376 0 0 1 .264-.111c.205 0 .375.17.375.375v2.625z"
        fill="#FFF" fill-rule="nonzero" transform-origin="center"/>
    </g>
  </svg>




thank you for the exanple and reference.

Or no CSS at all, with SVG SMIL animation
Cleaned your SVG with https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/# for brevity


<svg viewBox="0 0 240 240" style="width:160px;background:pink">
  <path fill="#000" d="m230 149c0 28-23 51-50 51-1 0-2 0-3 0v0h-117c-1 0-2 0-3 0-26-2-47-24-47-51 
                       0-22 13-40 32-48 2-25 22-45 47-45 5 0 10 1 14 2h0a50 50 90 0138-18c28 
                       0 50 23 50 51 0 2 0 5-1 7 24 6 40 26 40 51z"/>
  <path fill="#fff" d="m163 130c-5 21-22 35-44 35a45 45 90 01-31-12l-8 8a4 4 90 01-3 1 4 4 90 
                       01-4-4v-26c0-2 2-4 4-4h28c2 0 4 2 4 4 0 1 0 2-1 3l-8 8a30 30 90 0046-6c1-2 
                       2-5 3-7 0-1 1-1 2-1h11c1 0 2 1 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0zm2-21c0 2-2 4-4 4h-26a4 
                       4 90 01-4-4c0-1 0-2 1-3l8-8a30 30 90 00-20-8c-10 0-20 5-26 14-1 2-2 5-3 7 
                       0 1-1 1-2 1h-11a2 2 90 01-2-2v0c5-21 22-35 44-35 11 0 23 5 31 12l8-8a4 4 90 013-1c2 0 4 2 4 4v26z">
     <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate"
                       from="0 120 120" to="360 120 120" dur="4s" 
                       repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </path>
</svg>




well done! I missed this news... and I thought that the SMIL language was disappearing (while all the vocabulary of CSS animations comes from the advances of this language)! thanks!

Unless you are still on Chrome-45 (sept. 2015) ... Although Chrome 45 deprecated SMIL in favor of CSS animations and Web animations, the Chrome developers have since suspended that deprecation.

I don't understand your remark, you mean that your solution can't work on chrome-45 since it uses SMIL instructions?

Yes, 9 years ago, Google disabled SMIL in Chrome 45... and quickly enabled it again.. they don't own the Web

Please, this is HTML-5 !
There is no needs to use xmlns attribute.
And you must use a viewbox : width and height are standard interface rendering like any html elements...
by default in SVG (or HTML) the reference point is at coordinates { top:0, left:0 } and your rotation is therefore done around this point.
The easiest way is to position this point at the center of your SVG with transform-origin : center; which also corresponds to the center of your path with 2 curved arrows.


svg {
  width      : 180px;
  height     : 180px;
  background : lightblue;
  }
svg > .cloud {
  fill      : whitesmoke;
  }
svg > .circle-arrows {
  fill             : orange;
  transform-origin : center;
  animation        : loader 1.25s infinite;
  }
@keyframes loader {
    0% { rotate:   0deg; }
  100% { rotate: 180deg; }
  }
<svg viewbox="0 0 24 24">
  <path class="cloud" 
    d="M23 14.864C23 17.696 20.737 20 17.956 20c-.11 0-.236 0-.346-.016V20H6.044c-.11 0-.22 0-.33-.016
    C3.09 19.808 1 17.584 1 14.864c0-2.16 1.304-4.016 3.159-4.784.157-2.512 2.2-4.48 4.698-4.48.487 0 .959.08 1.399.224
    h.015A4.993 4.993 0 0 1 14.137 4c2.782 0 5.044 2.304 5.044 5.136 0 .24-.015.48-.062.72C21.35 10.4 23 12.432 23 14.864z"
    />
  <path class="circle-arrows"
    d="M16.348 12.98c-.499 2.072-2.209 3.52-4.372 3.52a4.492 4.492 0 0 1-3.082-1.243l-.755.757
    a.376.376 0 0 1-.264.111.378.378 0 0 1-.375-.375v-2.625c0-.205.17-.375.375-.375H10.5
    c.205 0 .375.17.375.375 0 .1-.04.193-.11.264l-.804.802a2.991 2.991 0 0 0 4.594-.62
    c.14-.23.21-.452.31-.687.03-.082.087-.134.176-.134h1.125c.106 0 .187.088.187.187 0 .013 0 .03-.005.042z
    m.152-2.105c0 .205-.17.375-.375.375H13.5a.378.378 0 0 1-.375-.375c0-.1.04-.193.11-.264l.81-.809A3.016 3.016 0 0 0 12 9
    c-1.043 0-2.01.539-2.555 1.43-.14.229-.21.451-.31.686-.03.082-.087.134-.176.134H7.793a.189.189 0 0 1-.187-.187
    v-.042C8.11 8.94 9.838 7.5 12 7.5c1.149 0 2.267.457 3.099 1.243l.762-.757a.376.376 0 0 1 .264-.111
    c.205 0 .375.17.375.375v2.625z"
    />
</svg>




As explained in the previous answers you need to set the transform-origin to "center" or using explicit coordinates "12px 12px"  - otherwise the rotation takes the default origin values 0,0.
If the rotation origin is not concentric with the viewBox you can may also combine transform-origin with transform-box:fill-box


 #circle-arrows {
    animation: loader 1.25s infinite;
   transform-origin:center;
   transform-box:fill-box;
  }

  @keyframes loader {
    0% {
      rotate: 0deg;
    }

    100% {
      rotate: 180deg;
    }
  }
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
      <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" />
      <path
        d="M23 14.864C23 17.696 20.737 20 17.956 20c-.11 0-.236 0-.346-.016V20H6.044c-.11 0-.22 0-.33-.016C3.09 19.808 1 17.584 1 14.864c0-2.16 1.304-4.016 3.159-4.784.157-2.512 2.2-4.48 4.698-4.48.487 0 .959.08 1.399.224h.015A4.993 4.993 0 0 1 14.137 4c2.782 0 5.044 2.304 5.044 5.136 0 .24-.015.48-.062.72C21.35 10.4 23 12.432 23 14.864z"
        fill="#000" fill-rule="nonzero" />
      <path id="circle-arrows"
        d="M14.35 13.98 c-.5 2.07-2.21 3.52-4.37 3.52a4.49 4.49 0 01-3.09-1.24l-.75 .75a0.38 .38 0 01-.27 .12 .38 .38 0 01-.37-.38v-2.62c0-.21 .17-.38 .37-.38h2.63c0.21 0 .38 .17 .38 .38 0 .09-.04 .19-.11 .26l-.81 .8a2.99 2.99 0 004.59-.62c0.15-.23 .22-.45 .32-.69 .02-.08 .08-.13 .17-.13h1.13c0.1 0 .18 .09 .18 .19 0 .01 0 .03 0 .04zm0.15-2.1c0 .2-.17 .37-.37 .37h-2.63a0.38 .38 0 01-.37-.37c0-.1 .03-.2 .1-.27l0.81-.81a3.02 3.02 0 00-2.04-.8c-1.04 0-2.01 .54-2.55 1.43-.15 .23-.22 .45-.32 .69-.02 .08-.08 .13-.17 .13h-1.17a0.19 .19 0 01-.18-.19v-.04c0.5-2.08 2.23-3.52 4.39-3.52 1.15 0 2.27 .46 3.1 1.24l0.76-.75a0.38 .38 0 010.27-.11c0.2 0 .37 .17 .37 .37v2.63z"
        fill="#FFF" fill-rule="nonzero" />
    </g>
  </svg>



The transform shorthand rotate property can still cause issues in some Safari/webkit browser versions – at least when applied to SVG elements.
For better cross browser compatibility opt for the verbose legacy notation
transform: rotate(180deg)

Besides, you should remove these properties/attributes

border-radius is not applicable to SVG elements
fill-rule has no effect as you don't have overlapping compound path shapes
you can reduce the animation to 1 state - 100% or to
editors like figma tend to add unnecessary bounding box rectangles like <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" />



<svg style="width:240px" viewbox="0 0 24 24" >
  <style>
    #circle-arrows {
      animation: loader 1.25s infinite forwards linear;
    }

    @keyframes loader {
      100% {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
      }
    }
  </style>
  <path d="M23 14.9c0 2.8-2.3 5.1-5 5.1-.2 0-.3 0-.4 0h0-11.6c-.1 0-.2 0-.3 0-2.6-.2-4.7-2.4-4.7-5.1 0-2.2 1.3-4.1 3.2-4.8 .1-2.5 2.2-4.5 4.7-4.5 .4 0 .9 .1 1.4 .2l0 0c0.9-1.1 2.3-1.8 3.8-1.8 2.8 0 5.1 2.3 5.1 5.1 0 .3 0 .5-.1 .8 2.3 .5 3.9 2.5 3.9 5z" />
  <path id="circle-arrows" fill="#fff" transform-origin="center" d="m16.35 12.98c-.5 2.07-2.21 3.52-4.37 3.52a4.49 4.49 0 01-3.08-1.24l-.76.76a.38.38 0 01-.26.11.38.38 0 01-.38-.38v-2.63c0-.2.17-.38.38-.38h2.62c.2 0 .38.17.38.38 0 .1-.04.19-.11.26l-.8.8a2.99 2.99 0 004.59-.62c.14-.23.21-.45.31-.69.03-.08.09-.13.18-.13h1.13c.11 0 .19.09.19.19 0 .01 0 .03-.01.04zm.15-2.1c0 .2-.17.38-.38.38h-2.62a.38.38 0 01-.38-.38c0-.1.04-.19.11-.26l.81-.81a3.02 3.02 0 00-2.04-.81c-1.04 0-2.01.54-2.56 1.43-.14.23-.21.45-.31.69-.03.08-.09.13-.18.13h-1.16a.19.19 0 01-.19-.19v-.04c.51-2.08 2.24-3.52 4.4-3.52 1.15 0 2.27.46 3.1 1.24l.76-.76a.38.38 0 01.26-.11c.2 0 .38.17.38.38v2.63z" />
</svg>

<h3>Loaded in img element</h3>
<img width="240" height="240" src="data:image/svg+xml,<svg viewBox='0 0 24 24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><style> %23circle-arrows { animation: loader 1.25s infinite linear; } @keyframes loader { to { transform: rotate(180deg); } } </style><path d='M23 14.9c0 2.8-2.3 5.1-5 5.1-.2 0-.3 0-.4 0h0-11.6c-.1 0-.2 0-.3 0-2.6-.2-4.7-2.4-4.7-5.1 0-2.2 1.3-4.1 3.2-4.8 .1-2.5 2.2-4.5 4.7-4.5 .4 0 .9 .1 1.4 .2l0 0c0.9-1.1 2.3-1.8 3.8-1.8 2.8 0 5.1 2.3 5.1 5.1 0 .3 0 .5-.1 .8 2.3 .5 3.9 2.5 3.9 5z'/><path id='circle-arrows' fill='%23fff' transform-origin='center' d='M16.35 12.98c-.5 2.07-2.21 3.52-4.37 3.52a4.49 4.49 0 01-3.08-1.24l-.76.76a.38.38 0 01-.26.11.38.38 0 01-.38-.38v-2.63c0-.2.17-.38.38-.38h2.62c.2 0 .38.17.38.38 0 .1-.04.19-.11.26l-.8.8a2.99 2.99 0 004.59-.62c.14-.23.21-.45.31-.69.03-.08.09-.13.18-.13h1.13c.11 0 .19.09.19.19 0 .01 0 .03-.01.04zm.15-2.1c0 .2-.17.38-.38.38h-2.62a.38.38 0 01-.38-.38c0-.1.04-.19.11-.26l.81-.81a3.02 3.02 0 00-2.04-.81c-1.04 0-2.01.54-2.56 1.43-.14.23-.21.45-.31.69-.03.08-.09.13-.18.13h-1.16a.19.19 0 01-.19-.19v-.04c.51-2.08 2.24-3.52 4.4-3.52 1.15 0 2.27.46 3.1 1.24l.76-.76a.38.38 0 01.26-.11c.2 0 .38.17.38.38v2.63z'/></svg>" alt="spinner">



For seamless looping animations you may also apply the
animation-timing-function: linear;
As you can see you can also convert your SVG to a self contained asset (for usage in an <img> or CSS background-image) by prepending the stylesheet directly to the SVG. In this case you need to add the xmlns namespace.
